# Why isn't my checkColor function running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody please help me to figure out why my checkColor function is not running for the 2nd and subsequent clicks once the requisite for the If loop it is dependent on is deemed True (which it is, according to Log)? It works for the first click, changing the button's color, and then it should in theory move from 5 to 4, and so forth, for each Click, changing the color of each button based on the assigned number to 'row'. It logs that this is indeed the case, that the 'row' and the 'someClass' object matches what I want it to, but it's not actually running. It just runs the log, but no actual change in color to the subsequent buttons. Thanks in advance.

```
// var playerOne = prompt("Player One: Enter your Name - You will be Blue.")
// var playerTwo = prompt("Player One: Enter your Name - You will be Red.")

var gClass = $(".G")
var fClass = $(".F")
var eClass = $(".E")
var dClass = $(".D")
var cClass = $(".C")
var bClass = $(".B")
var aClass = $(".A")

var buttons = $("button")

var row = 5
var locRow = 5
var someClass = 0
var locClass = 1
var someClassAttr = 0
var locClassAttr = 1


function returnBackgroundColor(rowIndex,colIndex){
  // console.log($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
  // console.log(rowIndex);
  return($(colIndex[rowIndex]).prop("background-color"));
}

function changeColor(locRow, someClass){
  someClass.eq(row).css("background-color","red");
}

function checkColor(locRow ,someClass){
    for (locRow; locRow > -1; locRow--) {
      if (returnBackgroundColor(locRow, someClass) === undefined){
        return changeColor(locRow, someClass);
      }else {
        false;
      }
    }
  }

buttons.on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') === 'G') {
    var someClass = gClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'F') {
    var someClass = fClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'E') {
    var someClass = eClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'D') {
    var someClass = dClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'C') {
    var someClass = cClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'B') {
    var someClass = bClass;
  }else if ($(this).attr('class') === 'A') {
    var someClass = aClass;
  }else {
    false;
  }
  someClassAttr = someClass.attr('class');
  if (locClassAttr === someClassAttr){
    locRow = locRow - 1;
    console.log(locRow, someClass);
    checkColor(locRow, someClass);
    // console.log(checkColor(locRow, someClass));
  }else {
    checkColor(row, someClass);
    var locClass = someClass;
    locClassAttr = locClass.attr('class');
    console.log(locClassAttr, someClassAttr);
  }
})
```

Comment: You have some bugs in your code. Maybe you can explain to us in more detail what exactly you want to develop. Can you also show us your markup and a screenshot or GIF? We need to be able to recreate the error to help.

Comment: Well, there is no runtime error or anything like that.

I'm trying to make it so that whenever I click on a certain column of buttons (a 6x7 grid of buttons), with each column being associated to a certain class, that button's bg-color attribute will be checked, and if it is undefined, then it will be changed to a different color. The goal is to recreate Connect Four, so it much check from the bottom of the column, per click, to change the colors of the buttons from the bottom up. 

Currently it changes the color of the bottom row, as it should, but it doesn't change any other after that.

Comment: Fixed it. I forgot to change row to locRow in one of my functions. Overlooked a very rookie mistake. Sorry for the bother. Works now.